# Can a Metadata package be pushed to a Developer Edition?

Tags: metadata-api, package

I have a Metadata copy of the managed package I work on. I have attempted lots of sfdx commands and sf commands. None of them have successfully pushed the package to my developer org. Any suggestions or considerations?

Answer (score 5):

`force mdapi deploy` is what you're looking for. If your working directory contains just one package (e.g. `package.xml` is in the root folder), you must also include `-s`.

In other words, if your files look like this:

```
+ classes
| class1
| class2
+ pages
| page1
| page2
package.xml
```

You *must* use `-s`, the Single Package flag.

If your files look like this:

```
+ package1
| + classes
| | class1
| | class2
| + pages
| | page1
| | page2
| package.xml
+ package2
|  + classes
|  | class3
|  | class4
| + pages
| | page3
| | page4
| package.xml
```

Then you must *not* use the `-s` flag.

You may deploy either as a folder (`-d`), or a zip file (`-f`).

Check your command parameters. Also, you will probably want to add a timeout (`-w`) so the CLI will update you on the progress as it deploys.

This command can deploy mdapi-formatted data to any organization with API enabled, including production, sandboxes, scratch orgs, developer orgs, and so on.

Comment: what if you don't have a package.xml at all, hypothetically?

Comment: @seekingPeace I have some ideas, but need to do some R&D. In the meantime, see if `force source convert` will work without one. That would be the easiest solution if it works.

Comment: @seekingPeace Just checked, `sf project generate manifest --source-dir <path>` will generate a package.xml for you, in the event you don't have one and can't get one from any source org.